# Checking if a POST[] variable is an IP address?

Tags: php

I'm making a script, in which the user needs to enter a valid IP address. How can I check that it's a valid IP address? (Doesn't need to resolve)

Basically `$_POST['ip']` just needs to be between `0.0.0.0` and `255.255.255.255`

Comment: I don't think you want to validate 0.0.0.0 as a valid IP...

Comment: @animuson: Its a perfectly valid route address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're running PHP >= 5.2, use the Filter extension:

```
filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)
```

More info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this until after I posted mine.

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly convenient. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `preg_match(/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/, $_POST['ip'])`.

More about `preg_match()` [here](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Also there are many patterns for validation. Choose most suitable one for you.

---

Update: Also about using filters. Not all servers have already PHP equal or higher, than 5.2.0. So u can check version before using them, but IMHO most logical ways would be Filters or PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split your "IP" string by "."
2. Verify that there are four entries (octet) in the array.
3. Verify: 0 <= octet <= 255
4. If you want to get fancier, you can check that the IP isn't in a private network, isn't a multicast network, or isn't in the reserved space.

Edit: Use the built in PHP method if available! :)

Comment: I think you meant: 0 ≤ octet ≤ 255.